# Index Match with Data Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

So i current have 2 scan sheets that i record barcode scans with. One to scan in items and the other to scan out items. I reference using index match to see if the item in scan log 1 is present in scan log two and check yes or no accordingly.
Some times i have multiple items with the same barcode, but it usually happens after a weeks span. Is there a way i can put a dual criteria where I can index and match if the the date from scan log 2 is greater then the date from scan log 1?

**SCAN LOG 1**

```
A           B         C

Date    Barcode    Check

12/1/16  212121       NO

12/2/16  222222      YES
```

**SCAN LOG 2**

```
A           B   

Date     Barcode    

12/4/16  222222
```

**EDIT:**

Current formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,'SCAN LOG 2'!B:B,1,false)),"NO","YES"))
```

Comment: Can you please provide the formula you are currently using to match?

Comment: currently im using a vlookup up formula to accomplish this. But I'd assume I'd used a idex, match, array formula for the multiple criteria with date criterias.

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,'SCAN LOG 2'!B:B,1,false)),"NO","YES"))

Comment: [This site](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) should help you with Index/Match and multiple criteria.  (there are many others too, just search for "index match multiple criteria")

Comment: Thanks for the edit and advise Bruce, I did indeed try looking up the specific formula i was looking for but to no avail. Ultimately I just need the formula to check if if the barcode is present in the second log within the last 2 weeks of the date range.

Comment: So, for your example, if Scan Log 2 had ` 12/1/2016` and `222222`, you want to return "No". **Only** when Scan Log 2's date is AFTER Scan Log 1's, you want the check to say "Yes"?  (I gotta run, but try something like this (this goes in C2 of your Scan Log 1: `=IF(INDEX(scanLog2Date,MATCH(B2,scanLog2Barcode,0))>$A2,"Yes","No")`. You'll probably have to fiddle with the ranges, but I think that works...